# (Android) Change ImageButton's Image after waiting after ButtonClick

Tags: android, button

I would like to press a button, where it will change the color of a button and play a sound, then wait time (t) then change the color of the button again.

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void OnClick(View v) {
    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_block); /* Changes Color */
    sp.play(sound,1,1,0,0,1); /*Plays sound*/
    //Wait t amount of time here
    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_block); /* Changes Color Again */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `postDelayed()` method like this

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void OnClick(View v) {
        button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_block); /* Changes Color */
        sp.play(sound,1,1,0,0,1); /*Plays sound*/
        //Wait t amount of time here
        button1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Do what you want
                button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_block); /* Changes Color Again */
            }
        },3*1000 /* This would be the milisecond you want to wait */);
    }
}
```

If you want to stop music too, you might need to change my code a bit.